# cabal: Encountered missing dependencies:

Tags: haskell, elm, cabal

I am trying to install a Haskell program (itself a [compiler](https://github.com/elm/compiler) for another programming language) from the Github repository.

The Elm compiler is itself a Haskell program and I would like to compile it from source:

```
$ cabal configure
Resolving dependencies...
Warning: solver failed to find a solution:
Could not resolve dependencies:
trying: elm-0.19.1 (user goal)
next goal: zip-archive (dependency of elm-0.19.1)
Dependency tree exhaustively searched.
Trying configure anyway.
Configuring elm-0.19.1...
cabal: Encountered missing dependencies:
SHA -any,
ansi-terminal ==0.8.*,
ansi-wl-pprint >=0.6.8 && <0.7,
containers >=0.5.8.2 && <0.6,
```

If I try to use a different command the computer searches for a different version of the Elm programming language.

```
$ cabal install elm
Resolving dependencies...
cabal: Could not resolve dependencies:
trying: Elm-0.13 (user goal)
trying: base-4.12.0.0/installed-4.1... (dependency of Elm-0.13)
next goal: transformers (dependency of Elm-0.13)
rejecting: transformers-0.5.6.2/installed-0.5..., transformers-0.6.0.2,
transformers-0.5.6.2, transformers-0.5.5.2, transformers-0.5.5.0,
transformers-0.5.4.0, transformers-0.5.2.0, transformers-0.5.1.0,
transformers-0.5.0.1, transformers-0.5.0.0 (conflict: Elm => transformers>=0.2
&& <0.5)
rejecting: transformers-0.4.3.0, transformers-0.4.2.0 (conflict:
```

I already have Elm installed globally and I would like to install a local copy that I cloned from Github.  The cabal [documentation](https://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/3.4/installing-packages.html#building-and-installing-packages) doesn't say much.

Helpful information:

```
$ ghc --version
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 8.6.5
$ cabal --version
cabal-install version 1.24.0.2
compiled using version 1.24.2.0 of the Cabal library
```

Trying different things possibly at risk:

```
$ cabal install --only-dependencies
Resolving dependencies...
internal error: could not construct a valid install plan.
The proposed (invalid) plan contained the following problems:
Package time is required by several packages, but they require inconsistent
versions:
package zip-archive-0.3.3 requires time-1.10
package snap-server-1.1.2.0 requires time-1.10
package snap-core-1.0.4.2 requires time-1.10
package io-streams-1.5.2.1 requires time-1.10
package http-client-0.6.4.1 requires time-1.10
package elm-0.19.1 requires time-1.10
package directory-1.3.6.2 requires time-1.10
package cookie-0.4.5 requires time-1.10
package HTTP-4000.3.16 requires time-1.10
package unix-2.7.2.2 requires time-1.8.0.2

Proposed plan:
Configured HTTP-4000.3.16 (.fake.HTTP-4000.3.16)
Configured SHA-1.6.4.4 (.fake.SHA-1.6.4.4)
Configured ansi-terminal-0.8.2 (.fake.ansi-terminal-0.8.2)
Configured ansi-wl-pprint-0.6.8.2 (.fake.ansi-wl-pprint-0.6.8.2)
Configured asn1-encoding-0.9.6 (.fake.asn1-encoding-0.9.6)
Configured asn1-parse-0.9.5 (.fake.asn1-parse-0.9.5)
Configured asn1-types-0.3.4 (.fake.asn1-types-0.3.4)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `cabal` is very old, and I strongly recommend you upgrade.

That said... with cabal-1, the invocation is simply

```
cabal install
```

with no `elm` at the end. Run it from within the directory you cloned from github that has a file named `elm.cabal` or similar -- it will automatically look for a file with extension `.cabal` and install the package described inside. `cabal install` will also take care of installing the missing dependencies.

With modern `cabal`, and assuming the executable named in the `.cabal` file is called `elm`, I would use

```
cabal run elm -- --args --for --elm --compiler
```

to run the compiler during testing, and then

```
cabal install --exe
```

when you are satisfied with your changes and want to make the executable available more widely.

Comment: I upgraded to `cabal 3.4` https://www.haskell.org/cabal/download.html